# ng add @angular/fire 'Server Error. certificate has expired'

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

> ng add @angular/fire 
>   ....
>
> audited 23085 packages in 14.519s
>   found 0 vulnerabilities
>   Server Error. certificate has expired

Using last versions : 
Angular CLI: 8.3.21 
Node: 10.16.0 
Angular: 8.2.14 
firebase-tools : 7.11.0

Already tried logout and login to firebase again but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Sounds like you need a new certificate at firebase.  I would start your check there.  Also, please share what you have tried to help SO users better understand what you've already done to resolve the issue.

Comment: how do you get a new firebase certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was trying to add @angular/fire to my project just to deploy it to firebase but it seems like there is a problem with "ng" commands when using firebase.
The only way i found to resolve this is using the native commands of firebase-tools :

> - firebase init
>     or firebase use --add "myprojectId"
> - firebase deploy

Answer (score 3):

try rolling the date on your system back to January 4th and run ng add @angular/fire, I'm having a similar issue and this fixed it however I would still like to know how to use this command and have the correct system time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have many versions of `firebase` installed. In my case, I had an alias (`fb`) pointing to one version while `firebase` was another.
All to say, really ensure you are invoking the version of firebase you believe you are (^_^) or this error can occur.