# Why does @angular/fire show: 'Server Error. certificate has expired', when I run: ng add @angular/fire?

Tags: angular, firebase

**Angular version:**

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.22
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.22
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.22
@angular/cli                      8.3.22
@angular/fire                     5.3.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.22
@schematics/angular               8.3.22
@schematics/update                0.803.22
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

*1.What does 'Server Error. certificate has expired' mean? 

2. How can I fix it?*

**~~~~EDIT~~~~**

- I erased my hard drive and installed a fresh operating system; still not working.
- Opened an issue on the angular/angularfire git page: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2285
- Found that the angular/fire package.JSON uses firebase tools 6.10.0 when firebase tools is up to 7.12.1 tried to fix by forcing the project to resolve a newer version of firebase-tools using resolutions in package.json with yarn at the suggestion of @wSedlacek on GitHub. Didn't work.
- I changed the system time to before this issue started happening and it now works, issue still not fixed because it is a minor inconvenience to roll system time back to January 4th, 2020 every time you want to start a project.
- @wSedlacek found that an HTTPS cert is expiring the due to the older version of firebase-tools in the package.json had a cert that expired on either January 5th 2020.

This issue might be related since it started happening at the same time :
[Why is angular fire saying I'm not logged in even though firebase tools says I am?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708929/why-is-angular-fire-saying-im-not-logged-in-even-though-firebase-tools-says-i-a)

Here is a picture of the error:
[image: error picture]

Comment: What version of angular cli (ng)?

Comment: added the version to the post

Comment: Looks like someone else had this issue and answered their own question with a work-around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654027/ng-add-angular-fire-server-error-certificate-has-expired

Comment: I might also suggest opening an issue with the @angular/fire (angular/angularfire2) project: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues

Comment: I'm worried I led you astray and the issue might be with npm and its registry cert. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15416 curiously, this issue was opened 1/6/2017 and [someone mentions](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15416#issuecomment-271639238) getting an expired certificate from 2014. Every 3 years?

Comment: all of these things helped me, however I now have to manually link the firebase project to the angular project; hopefully the people at angular fire will give me an answer

Comment: I looked up similar issues not limited to angular, I changed the system time to before this issue started happening and it now works, how can I fix this but still have the correct time on my system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be issue due to older version of Firebase CLI . 

Try this command first `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest` and then run `ng add @angular/fire`

Comment: This is technically right, it has to do with @angular fire using an old build of firebase-tools.

Answer (score -1):

For me I kept getting the schematics error with `ng add @angular/fire`, so I had to work around it with:

`npm uninstall @angular/fire` then `npm i @angular/fire`... otherwise it didn't work.