# Why is angular fire saying I'm not logged in even though firebase tools says I am?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cli

I'm having an issue with my ng add @angular/fire command and I think this might have something to do with it. below is a screenshot of me checking my login by running firebase login, it clearly says I'm logged in. then I run a deploy to firebase command and it says " You're not logged into Firebase. Logging you in..."

```
Date: 2020-01-12T23:18:12.366Z - Hash: 0398eefc1b5a238b8b7e - Time: 37932ms
 Your application is now available at https://devinterface-78409.firebaseapp.com/
Raphaels-MacBook-Pro:devInterface raphael_castro$ firebase login
Already logged in as raphael@rcincorporated.net
Raphaels-MacBook-Pro:devInterface raphael_castro$ ng run devInterface:deploy
 You're not logged into Firebase. Logging you in...
 Building "devInterface"
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
```

I've reinstalled npm, firebase, angular/fire, and angular to try and resolve this issue; no dice.
here is my angular versions:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.20
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.20
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.20
@angular/fire                     5.2.3
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.20
@schematics/angular               8.3.20
@schematics/update                0.803.20
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please don't post pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and find with search engines.

Comment: fixing now sorry